# HDD orientation - does it matter?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, desktop-computer

I have raid 10 with 4 x Seagate HDDs. The disks are almost 10 yo. And suddenly one started to fail.

That one is mounted vertically (the PC case I use now has only 3 horizontal mounts for HDDs and 1 vertical, previous 8 yrs they were all horizontal).

I wonder if vertical orientation killed it. Any information based on actual experience? *(I know they supposed to work either way but also.. things what not supposed to happen happen)*

Comment: aha cool. angry layabouts from SO leaked into superuser too.. good bye world

Comment: Looking at MicroVAX II hardware from many years ago the HDDs had various slots. In addition to the "expected" installation, there were slots that flipped the disk to-to-bottom and a slot at a 45 degree angle. Many current disk arrays have the HDDs slide in from the top so you can access 60+ disks in a single array - simply slide the array partly out of the rack and remove the top cover. The mount angles do not matter for disk operation or longevity.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/13839/does-orientation-affect-hard-drive-lifespan backblaze uses a vertical orientation and they have more drives than I do https://www.backblaze.com/b2/hard-drive-test-data.html